# Custom field lookup not returning all matching values for filter criteria

Tags: filters, lookup-filter, criteria

I have created a lookup field with required filter type that filters on specific criteria within the lookup objects.  During testing I noted the lookup field only returning 1 value as an option when there are several values (28 potential values) that match the criteria I filtered.  How do I make my lookup field display all potential values?

[image: custom field definition screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to check following points:
1. make sure that you have permission to all 28 records.
2. Lookup Filter criteria is also case sensitive. So please also make sure that all 28 records are satisfying filter criteria.
3. Also When you click on lookup icon only recent records are shown some time. So try to search some record which satisfy filter criteria.

Comment: Thank you.  My problem is #3.  Lookup is only showing recently viewed records.  Any thoughts on how to show all, not just recently viewed?  I will research as well...

Answer (score 2):

**PARTIAL SOLUTION FOR THIS ISSUE:**

I also had the same issue and I noticed that **lookup fields** targeting an **object which can't be accessed via a tab display automatically all the records**.

Example : if, for instance, your lookup field lookup on the standard object Account. Then Only the most recently viewed Accounts will be shown as the standard object Account is being assigned a tab by default.

On the contrary, if your lookup field lookup on a custom object for which any tab has been assigned, then your lookup field will display by default all the records.
If you create later a tab for the custom object which is targeted by the lookup field you have created above then this one will not display all the records anymore but only the most recently viewed. 
The opposite applies if you delete the tab.

I hope this help a little bit. I haven't found any documentation describing this behavior however.

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable Enhanced Lookups on the object under Search Settings and see if that changes the return on what you are searching by.